# How to access API with AAD token from Contextual Outlook add-ins

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

By referring to all the outlook web add-in documentation online, I cannot find a way to access an API with bearer token from [Contextual Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins).

One of the obvious road blockers is the behavior of contextual card which disappeared if your mouse clicks on other places/windows. And I have to clicks on the pop-up login window in order to login...

I was wondering if there's anyone knows any solution.
Thanks.

Here is the current flow:

1. My RegEx rule matches activate contextual detection in email content (read mode).
2. I click the highlight text to open the contextual card and see my add-in content powered by a web server.
3. My add-in code asks user to login to get user token, so that we can use the token to authenticate to another API. (In short, our backend API doesn't want to be public and non-Auth). Outlook pop-up a separate window for login.
4. I move my mouse to clicks on the button in the login window. At the same time, contextual card disappeared.
5. Maybe the code successfully get the user token, but the add-in is terminated before got the token.

Comment: Which platform do you get such issue? outlook web or desktop? thank you

Comment: Outlook desktop

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. This bug is currently in our backlog. We do not have a timeline to share at this time.

Comment: Thanks, is there any link I can track the status?

Comment: This bug is being tracked in our internal backlog, and currently we do not expose this.